# Can anybody tell me what is the dome shaped object in this picture?

Tags: electrical

[image]

I seen a red beam coming from it and the. It went away

Comment: Not sure why someone would down vote this question, I agree it is some type of motion sensor, when you move around it may have a indicator (the red light) that lets you know it detects movement. It may be for an alarm or lighting.+

Answer (score 5):

That is a motion sensor.   It relates to either a burglar alarm or motion detector lighting.

The lighting isn't going to light up during the day, it also has a light sensor so it knows when it is not daylight.